# Getting specific user data from Meteor Presence

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

With Meteor Presence, I can return the userId's of the usetrs that are online but. I would like to see how to get back the user object.

```
Meteor.publish('userPresence', function() {
  return Meteor.presences.find({}, {fields: {state: true, userId: true}});
});
```

As you can see Im publishing the collection and also subscribing to it:

```
Meteor.subscribe('userPresence');
```

I have a view that has an each block in it to get all online users:

```
<template name="presenceList">
   <h1>{{onlineCount}}</h1>
   {{#each onlineUsers}}
      {{> presenceSingle}}
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

And also this is file that has the helpers in:

```
Template.presenceList.helpers({
    onlineUsers: function() {
    return Meteor.presences.find();
   },
   onlineCount: function() {
    return Meteor.presences.find().count();
   }
});
```

My biggest struggle is return the user name in my single user template.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add underscore package

```
mrt add underscore
```

Then you can update your onlineUsers to

```
onlineUsers: function() {
  var users = _.map(Meteor.presences.find().fetch(), function(user) { 
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id :user.userId})
  });
  return users;
}
```

All I am doing above is making a new array with the returned objects from the Meteor.users.findOne({_id :user.userId}) using underscore's _.map see [link](http://underscorejs.org/#map)

Finally, your presenceSingle template

```
<template name="presenceSingle">
  <p>{{_id}}</p>
  <p>{{createdOn}}</p>
  <p>{{emails.0.address}}</p>
  <br/>
</template>
```

Here I am returning the _id, createdAt and email address fields for each user's mongo document. You can return any fields you like. Note the handlebars syntax for returning the email address. emails is an array of 1 element but we access the elements using emails.0 not emails[0]

Comment: jamin you are ace thanks so much. I didint even need to install underscore as it seems it looks like it might already have it. Anyway all is good apart from the fact I gte this logging error.

`Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch`

Any idea what it might be thats causing it?

Comment: Actually looks like I may have spoke too soon. At first I didnt think the error was breaking anything but I now realise that it is in fact not updating if I login with other users.

Comment: Sam no worries. I think that is an actual meteor bug... It was throwing that error on Chrome but not on Firefox.

Comment: Any idea how to return just users that are logged in. If i visite the site without logging in it still adds me to the count. 

I think I can add a filter here `return Meteor.presences.find({}, {fields: {state: true, userId: true}});` but not sure what to add to return just logged in users

Comment: Right ok, yes correct it looks like that error code is juts a bug and it is in fact working,so once again thank you. Secondly it looks as if the presence is returning all people who hit the site regardless of whether they are users or not. Im assuming this can be got round by using a filter.

Any thirdly, it looks as if its not returning the other users info, Im assuming this is a security thing is there anyway I can allow the users publication to send the username to all users? Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: use    Meteor.presences.find({ userId: { $exists: true}}) for your presence find queries. You can change both the onlineUsers and onlineCount to use this. If a user is not logged in they do not have a userId. Can you mark my answer if I have helped? Thanks :)

Comment: `Meteor.presences.find({ userId: { $exists: true}})`

Comment: Yeah sure will mark it now. Any chance you know why its not returning the other logged in usernames only the one that is logged in.

Comment: It will be because you have updated both queries in onlineCount and onlineUsers. If you want the usernames of all users displayed then revert the Meteor.presence.find query in onlineUsers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30046/discussion-between-jamin79-and-sam-mason)

Comment: You'll want to add underscore anyways, Meteor depends on it anyways but the documentation recommends you add it or your code will break when they remove the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You have the ids of the users in the doc returned from Meteor.presences.find() right? Why dont you run a query to fetch the individual user object from Mongo

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: theIDFromDoc});
```

Comment: How would I add this to a template helper, for it to get the object back. ANd how do I got about getting the ID from the doc?